# C# Simple Error/Crash/Freeze-Log

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, backgroundworker, freeze

I'm looking for a simple way to collect and log (to file) freezes/crashes/exceptions etc.

My Program runs fine for some time but stops working (Backgroundworkerthread seems to stop working), also writing the values its reading from an API stops.
Traybar-menu is still working fine.

Nothing to find in the Windows-Logs or somewhere else.

I dont have a guess where or how to start the search!

Thanks so far!

Comment: Try writing to the application log.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/42ste2f3(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I am not completely sure what you want to do, but for debugging programs I think the System.Diagnostics namespace is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a piece of software which you can implement in your C# Project. It's called Log4Net.

The article below explains how to implement and use Log4Net:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial

Using Log4Net will give you the oppertunity to log and view any exceptions that might occur in the future. Giving you the advantage to fix them faster!

Comment: thanks! thats what im looking for! im going to implement this and see why my backgroundprocess keeps freezing!